# Write Spark dataframe to database (Exasol) using jdbc slow

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I am reading from AWS(s3) and writing in to database (exasol) taking too much time even setting batchsize is not effecting performance.
I am writing 6.18m rows (around 3.5 gb) taking 17min

running in cluster mode 20 node cluster

how I can make it fast

Dataset ds = session.read().parquet(s3Path)

ds.write().format("jdbc").option("user", username).option("password", password).option("driver", Conf.DRIVER).option("url", dbURL).option("dbtable", exasolTableName).option("batchsize", 50000).mode(SaveMode.Append).save();

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's an interesting question.

I did not check the implementation details of recently released Spark connector. But you may go with some previously existing methods.

1. Save Spark job results as CSV files in Hadoop. Run standard parallel IMPORT from all created files via WebHDFS http calls.
2. Official [UDF script](https://github.com/exasol/hadoop-etl-udfs) is capable of importing directly from Parquet, as far as I know.
3. You may implement your own Java UDF script to read Parquet in way you want. For example, this is how it works for [ORC files](https://gist.github.com/wildraid/8a720e3df2ce1fa185292c581c44293c).

Generally speaking, the best way to achieve some real performance is to bypass Spark altogether.